# Recommended prefix for user defined shortcut chords in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any recommended prefix for user defined chords? (chord = two separate keypress actions) I mean some prefix that is ensured not to be used by the core editor in the future and is also discouraged for extensions to use, like there is one in, for example, Emacs.

Every time I want to define my own shortcuts I find that most reasonable keyboard combinations are already taken, so I would like to put all my keyboard customizations under one single prefix.

Comment: Have you tried having same keybindings for separate context using advanced customisation ?

For reference please refer : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization

Basically you could use same key bindings performing different actions under differen circumstances by using when clause

Comment: I know about contextual bindings, but it's not really what I'm looking for. What I need is some "safe place" to define my own bindings.